# Why does my while-loop not stop?

Tags: java, file, while-loop

I dont know why my loop is keep looping infinitily..

**URLLinks**

```
public String findFile() {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("urls.txt"))) {

        String sCurrentLine;

        if ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

            break;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return findFile();

}
```

I just want to print sCurrentLine one time, but it keeps printing it out infinitily..
I think the problems lays in *return findFile()* but I dont know how to fix it.

Cheers

**UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE again**

I fixed the problem by making the method `findFile()` to `void`, and changed from a while-loop to an if-statement

**URLLinks UPDATED CODE**

```
public void findFile() {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("urls.txt"))) {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I think the problems lays in return findFile()*" => good guess! "*I dont know how to fix it.*" => return something else (or nothing)!

Comment: recurssion recurssion!!

Comment: "return null;"!? If you don't want it to return anything then change its return type from String to void

Comment: Also; your while statement will only ever run once because it has a `break;` in it (that is called during the loop in all cases). Are you trying to do this? If so consider an if statement

Comment: Yes that is the purpose, but I have tried an if-statement, but it still makes recurssion

Comment: Yes the while loop issue is not whats causing the recurssion, it is a problem in its own right. You are simulating an `if` using a `while`. There is no good reason for doing this.

Comment: Ooooh my bad, I thought the while-loop caused the problem, but it doesnt. I have changed it to an if-statement. Thx @Richard Tingle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is infinite recursion as `findFile()` always calls itself. Something other than `return findFile();` is required, but it is unclear what the purpose of the function is, perhaps just:

```
return sCurrentLine; // with 'sCurrentLine' declared prior try
```

The loop seems unrequired as it exits after it reads the first line.

Comment: +1. You beat me by 7 seconds.

Comment: But before `return sCurrentLine`, he has to extact it outside the `try/catch` block.

Comment: Yes I thought that was it, thx :)

Comment: Well the purpose of the function is to read from a textfile, and display whats in it, after pressing a JButton

But what do you mean about "//with sCurrentLine declared prior try ?

Comment: @ymerdrengene, if `sCurrentLine` is going to be used as the return value then it would need to be declared outside of the `try{}` so it is visible. However, from your description it appears the function does not need to return anything so change return type to `void`.

Comment: Hmm I don't know why, but when I used void it didn't work, but now it seems to work.. so strange haha. Anyways thx @hmjd

Answer (score 1):

The while loop does stop; the problem is you're creating an infinite recursion by calling the method from within itself. To solve this, you could for example do one of these things:

1) Change the return type of the method to void, and delete the return statement. Then the method will not return anything, just exit after printing the first line (due to the break statement).

or:

2) Return a String instead, eg. sCurrentLine, which in your current code will just take the value of the first line in the file (due to the break statement in the while loop).

The above outcomes will of course only take place if the file can be opened (otherwise the code throws an exception), and if the file is not empty (otherwise it will never enter the while loop).

Comment: Thx for the answer @zsukosd!
I have used the 1st suggestion :)